# android to REST : cannot serialize java Date

Tags: java, json, rest, gson, retrofit2

I have an android app that uses retrofit2 along with Jackson to serialize a set of classes, so as to send them to a mysql database via a REST api.

All class fields are serialized fine, except from the ones with a type Date. Prior to the POST to the rest API they have normal values, but they arrive to the REST receiving function as nulls.

I have browsed SO and tried switching to GSON as many threads suggested, using the retrofit client initialization below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .setDateFormat(Utils.DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT)
           .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
              @Override
              public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                                  JsonDeserializationContext context)
                                          throws JsonParseException {
                        return new Date();
              }
            }).registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
                  @Override
                  public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, 
                                        JsonSerializationContext context) {
                        Gson ggson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(
                                      Utils.DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT).create();
                        return new JsonPrimitive(ggson.toJson(src));
                  }
               }).create();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
               .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient(token))
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
               .build();
```

Breaking inside the serializer function shows that Dates are indeed converted to the appropriate String format. However, they arrive as nulls to the REST receiver.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue as well previously! I end up using a @GET call to the rest server that returns the date. I copied the format and did a print out from json on my android. I found out I didn't need the millisecond. 
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" ) <- I removed the Z. Maybe for your case you need to make sure it's accepting/expecting the right format. I used this link for the format http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried several date formats but none works.

Comment: Did you change the field name in the database recently? I also got an issue with my string showing as null and I just realised my getter and setter were pointing to old name in the server side. Annoyingly I found out the resolution for this  besides updating my field name on the pojo class but also rename the getter and setter method to have the same name as the field name. getFIELD_NAME and setFIELD_NAME. I really have no clue why it's like that tho.

Comment: No, I have not changed the field name in the database. However, the GET call works fine, and I can retrieve the date field. Only when I am trying to post a date in the database, it does not work.